# Backend log: PHP Warning: file_put_contents(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/assets/coments/comentslist.txt)

Tags: javascript, php

When I run a PHP script in which I want data from my change to be written to a file, I get an error in the host log Backend log: PHP Warning: file_put_contents(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/assets/comments/commentslist.txt) is not within the allowed path(s)

I granted all necessary permissions(

javascript

```
function saveCommentToFile(comment) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "/assets/coments/save_comment.php", true); // Correct path
        var comentsave = comment;

    
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    
    
    const data = "comment=" + encodeURIComponent(comentsave);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };

    xhr.send(data);
}
```

php

```
<?php
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

$filePath = "/assets/coments/comentslist.txt";

file_put_contents($filePath, $comment . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);


?>
```

Help solve this problem! Please